# password_verify, don't understand why is not working | PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

> **ANSWER** 
> I changed
>   $verifyPassword = password_verify('$password', $row['userpassword']);
>  to
>  $verifyPassword = password_verify($password,
>   $row['userpassword']);
>
> And my userpassword VARCHAR was VARCHAR(50) and I changed it to
>   VARCHAR(255)

I'm trying to make a login system in PHP with MYSQL, I have made the signup part, and it hashes the password. [Signup is working].

Now I'm working on the login part, but it doesn't work, I have tried for some time now and I can't figure it out...

When I try to log in and I type the right username and password, I get "wrong password".

I have tried to echo the `$password` and `$row['userpassword]`, and I'm getting the string I need.

I can't understand why it's not working. :(

*hashed password in the table

```
$2y$10$qb9z5oRo4reF84.N.coQ8.itQPcOSvpeLdeWgL6uKkG
```

database table: users

```
+------+--------+---------------+------------+<br>
|userid|username|useremail      |userpassword|<br>
+------+--------+---------------+------------+<br>
|7     |admin   |email@gmail.com|hash*       |<br>
+------+--------+---------------+------------+<br>
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Page title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/desktop.css">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="config/login.config.php" method="POST">
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="login_username" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="username">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="password" name="login_password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="password">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" name="login_submit">LOG IN</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```php
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['login_submit'])) {
  require 'dbc.php';

  $username = $_POST['login_username'];
  $password = $_POST['login_password'];

  if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    header('Location: ../login.php?error=emptyfields');
    exit();
  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT username, userpassword FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        #echo $password;
        #echo "<br>";
        #echo $row['userpassword'];
        $verifyPassword = password_verify('$password', $row['userpassword']);
        if ($verifyPassword == false) {
          echo "password wrong";
         } else if($verifyPassword == true) {
          echo "logged in!";
         } else {
           echo "password error";
         }
      }
    } else {
      header('Location: ../login.php?noUserFound');
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: `password_verify('$password', $row['userpassword']);` should be `password_verify($password, $row['userpassword']);`. Also, why do you use while (I suppose username is unique)

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @PavelTřupek I tried, didn't work :( I don't know really, is there a better way? :)

Comment: @xmastertje I'm not getting any.

Comment: @Dharman, So I should do: $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['login_username']); ?

Comment: No, you should use prepared statements!

Comment: @Dharman okay thanks, I'll read up on that :)

Comment: Your DB columns should be at least `VARCHAR(60)`, but it would be best to have it set as `VARCHAR(255)`. I think yours is only 50.

Comment: @orc13a your hash seems quite short. How long is your userpassword column?

Comment: @Dharman,  is was only varchar(50) I have changed it to 255 now :)

Comment: @orc13a btw. password_verify returns boolean (true or false), so your "password error" can never be achieved ...

Comment: @orc13a your password in the table in the hash so input password make hash and compare.

Comment: @SubhashPatel that is not correct. When you run `password_hash` again it will generate a random hash and the values cannot possibly match. The correct way to verify a password is using `password_verify`.

Comment: @orc13a use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Dharman Like this: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) or is there better ways?

Comment: Yes, read also the official links I posted above.

Comment: You should post answer as answer not edit in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned the your code is not secure for SQL injections, thus to have a poor security use the addslashes function and with all fixes your code is :

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['login_submit'])) {
  require 'dbc.php';

  $username = addslashes ($_POST['login_username']);
  $password = addslashes ($_POST['login_password']);

  if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    header('Location: ../login.php?error=emptyfields');
    exit();
  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT username, userpassword FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        #echo $password;
        #echo "<br>";
        #echo $row['userpassword'];
        $verifyPassword = password_verify($password, $row['userpassword']);
        if ($verifyPassword == false) {
          echo "password wrong";
         } else if($verifyPassword == true) {
          echo "logged in!";
         } else {
           echo "password error";
         }
      }
    } else {
      header('Location: ../login.php?noUserFound');
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: 1. This does not answer the question. 2. `addslashes` are not a solution to SQL injection. Read my comment above. 3. Why do you recommend OP to implement poor security?

Comment: Who upvoted this answer? Please do not support poor programming practices!